# Magento: Controller override not working

Tags: magento, controller, overriding

Attempting to override the Cms/controllers/IndexController.

This is the directory structure of my module -

- Local/MyCompany/FourOhFourExp/controllers/IndexController.php
- Local/MyCompany/FourOhFourExp/etc/config.xml

The code for my IndexController is

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage'. DS .'Cms'. DS .'controllers'. DS .'IndexController.php';

class MyCompany_FourOhFourExp_IndexController extends Mage_Cms_IndexController
{
    public function noRouteAction($coreRoute = null){
        Mage::log('First Function');
        header("Location: new_route.html");
        die();
    }

    public function defaultNoRouteAction()
    {
        Mage::log('Second function!');
        header("Location: new_route.html");
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

and this is the code for my config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_FourOhFourExp>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyCompany_FourOhFourExp>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <cms>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MyCompany_FourOhFourExp before="Mage_Cms">MyCompany_FourOhFourExp</MyCompany_FourOhFourExp>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </cms>
        </routers>
        <events>
            <controller_action_noroute>
                <observers>
                    <cms>
                        <class>cms/observer</class>
                        <method>noRoute</method>
                    </cms>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_noroute>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Hoping someone can explain why this isn't overriding. I've looked through numerous tutorials and blog posts but have yet to figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: I believe it is unnecessary to extend `Mage_Cms_IndexController`, you can extend `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` instead.  This saves calling `require_once` which is incorrect when a site has compilation enabled.

Comment: I'm trying to overwrite the original so it shouldn't even compile the other controller and I'm not overwriting all the functions, just 1-2 so I'm using the require to pull that document in. This is my first attempt at this override and it's frustrating to be struggling so hard on something that seems straight forward, but then again, I guess nothing in development ever is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of issue:

1)Modulepath:

As your controller class is  `MyCompany_FourOhFourExp_IndexController` then path of class should be

```
app/code/local/MyCompany/FourOhFourExp
```

1. Local/MyCompany/controllers/IndexController
2. Local/MyCompany/etc/config.xml

change to

1. Local/MyCompany/FourOhFourExp/controllers/IndexController/php
2. Local/MyCompany/FourOhFourExp/etc/config.xml

2)**Mage cms controller donot add properly**

```
require_on Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Cms'). DS .'IndexController.php';
```

Comment: I appologize, but the module path you suggested was the one I'm using. I made the adjustment in my question

Comment: Folder had a lower case first letter and was being called incorrectly. Copied code to seperate file and worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

What need to do:

- add to app/code/local/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php ,  `Mage::dispatchEvent('cms_controller_action_noroute', array('action'=>$this));`
- in your custom module, catch the Event